# Pick the row and column of an DateFrame cell where the value true

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

In a DataFrame I have to find a specific value. If it exists I need the cell coordinates (row/column). Currently I get only the row and struggle with the column.

```
values = [[100.0, 127.0], [17.0, 24.13], [151.13, 0.0]]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate(values).reshape(3,2))

# df: 
#         0       1
# 0  100.00  127.00
# 1   17.00   24.13
# 2  151.13    0.00

v17 = df.isin([17,17])

# v17: 
#        0      1
# 0  False  False
# 1   True  False
# 2  False  False

row = v17.loc[v17[0] == True].index.values

# row = [1]
```

How can I get the row and column of a cell with a specific value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `np.where`

```
s,v=np.where(df==17)
df.columns[v]
Out[244]: Int64Index([0], dtype='int64')
df.index[s]
Out[245]: Int64Index([1], dtype='int64')
```

Comment: It's worth pointing about that a dataframe is not required for this. It will also work with: `s, v = np.where(np.concatenate(values).reshape(3,2)==17)`